# Error "tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/register.h not found" en flutter ios

Tags: flutter, ios, tensorflow

Estoy usando el paquete **tflite_v2** en flutter, pero he estado teniendo problemas en ios al momento de compilar (en android todo va bien) me dice que no encuentra el archivo "register.h" en el archivo `TflitePlugin.mm.`

En la documentación del paquete menciona que si está el error es porque se ha cambiado la ruta que es cambiar este:

```
"tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
```

por este:

```
"tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/register.h"
```

O sea solo es añadir el **contrib**, pero aún así sigue saliendo el error. No se si me haga falta instalar algo de tensorflow. Ya intenté de todo, abriendo el proyecto desde el `.xcworkspace` y desde el `.xcodeproject`, reinstalé pods, también hice un flutter clean y eso, pero nada.

El error está en el archivo `TflitePlugin.mm`